# Can i use bytes which in decimal have negative values as positive values

Tags: java, byte, signed

If i have these methods as below :

```
public int add (int a , int b) {


 assert(a>= 0 && a < 256 && b >= 0 && b < 256);

 // the addition is simply an xor operation in GF (256) since we are working on modulo(2) then 1+1=0 ; 0+0=0; 1+0=0+1=1;

    return a ^ b;

}
```

The second method is:

```
public int FFMulFast(int a, int b){
int t = 0;;

if (a == 0 || b == 0)

return 0;

 // The multiplication is done by using lookup tables. We have used both logarithmic and exponential table for mul
// the idea is firstly look to Logarithmic table then add their powers and find the corresponding of this to exponential table

t = (Log[(a & 0xff)] & 0xff) + (Log[(b & 0xff)] & 0xff);

if (t > 255) t = t - 255;

return Exp[(t & 0xff)];

}
```

Now i want to use these methods for calculating polynomial f(x)=a0+a1x + a2 x (pow 2) + ... a2 x (pow k-1) where these coefficients a0 , a1 , a2 i have generated as below :

```
 public void generate (int k) {
byte a [] = new byte [k];

Random rnd = new SecureRandom () ;

a.nextBytes (a); // the element of byte array are also negative as for example -122; -14; etc 

}
```

Now i want to calculate my polynomial but i am not sure if it works because of this negative coefficients . I know JAVA supports only signed bytes but i am not sure if the method below will work properly :

```
private int evaluate(byte x, byte[] a) {

    assert x != 0; // i have this x as argument to another method but x has //only positive value so is not my concern , my concern is second parameter of //method which will have also negative values
    assert a.length > 0;
    int r = 0;
    int xi = 1;
    for (byte b : a) {

        r = add(r, FFMulFast(b, xi));
        xi = FFMulFast(xi, x);
}
    return r;
}
```

Any suggestion please? Also if this one is not working can anyone suggest me how to turn negative values to positive ones without using masking because then it will be changed data type to int  and then i cant use getBytes(a) method

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Is not working this is why i am asking . But i am not sure if the problem is to these coefficients or to another method which use these polynomials for each byte of the file  . The one i did not present here . So i am not sure where the error is here or to another one  .  Something i am sure is that multiplication and addition method are working good . I will appreciate if you  can take a look to my code above and give me a clue

Comment: @johnsmith Could you briefly state the overall goal? And the reason behind your using bytes and the getBytes(..) method?

Comment: Then you should do some debugging.

Comment: `add(3, 3)` returns 0, and that is not any kind of "add" I've ever seen.

Comment: @Andreas - Have you seen Galois-Field arithmetic?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I thought it looked like the OP was trying to implement a bit-wise addition (something along the lines of a full adder) like this [one](https://github.com/dray92/Programming-Questions/blob/master/ctci/Hard18_1.java). Am I incorrect?

Comment: @DebosmitRay - OP is trying to do GF(256) arithmetic, AFAICT.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'which *in decimal' have negative values as positive values'. If this is a roundabout way of saying that bytes are signed in Java, they are.

Comment: @Andreas i am calculating arithmetic operation in extension fields where 1+1 = 0 because GF(256) is GF(2pow8) that means we will have 256 element fields with coefficients 0,1 that means 1+1 = 2 but 2 is not element of mod (2) so here addition is xor operation . So it is sutraction

Answer (score 0):

```
for (byte b : a) {
        r = add(r, FFMulFast(b, xi));
        xi = FFMulFast(xi, x);
}
```

If the `add()` and `FFMulFast()` methods expect positive values, you will have to use:

```
for (byte b : a) {
        r = add(r, FFMulFast(b & 0xff, xi));
        xi = FFMulFast(xi, x & 0xff);
}
```